# How to create a customized login page that logs in to Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am working on Odoo 14 Community Edition.

I would like to create a customized login page (I already know how to create a login page). However, what I need to know are:

1. How can I connect this customized login page to the Odoo system? The customized login page will have all of the required information that Odoo needs. I know I need to call an API or redirect to a URL, but which one?
2. How to configure Odoo to display my customized page as the login landing page instead of the default one?

I know there are 2 questions here but with only either one of these two the main question cannot be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to render your custom login page instead of default one, either you will have to modify the odoo controller which renders the template or modify the template which is rendered using the controller.

The controller is:

```
@http.route('/web/login', type='http', auth="none")
```

And the template is:

```
<template id="web.login" name="Login">
```

Comment: I tried inheriting the template and replacing the original form with the same content of the original, but when I login it gives me this error. File "D:\Odoo-Dev\odoo\fields.py", line 1162, in compute_value fields = records.pool.field_computed[self]      KeyError: res.users.tz.
Any clues?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: and is there a way to remove/hide the nav and footer only in the login page?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the <t t-call="web.login_layout"> wrapping from the template.

Comment: I just inherit the template into my custom module and copy the original form to replace it in the same place to see if it works with just the same content. See [the code that I copied here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/04d5b0d863634652d14eeb822eabd27627567e1f/addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml#L570-L609).

Comment: You can use the  <xpath expr="//t" position="replace"> to replace the entire template.

Comment: That indeed solves the error and remove the nav and footer. Please bear with me another continuous question. After removing the login_layout, the css file that I inherit web.assets_frontend does not work anymore. I need to use css for the page. How to make it possible? Last problem I think.

Comment: <t t-call="web.frontend_layout">
            <t t-set="html_data" t-value="{'style': 'height: 100%;'}"/>
            <t t-set="body_classname" t-value="'bg-100'"/>
            <t t-set="no_header" t-value="True"/>
            <t t-set="no_footer" t-value="True"/>


Try using this,